# pre-select from loop

Tags: php, html-select

So I made this car statistics calculation module, which after doing some calculations returns to show the results and then show the car I've jsut calculated for as the pre-selectedon in my form.

For this I made a function in php, I could use within my html:

```
function biler () {                         
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       if ($row['reg'] == $_GET['bil']){
           $selected = 'selected="selected"';
       }                    
       echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['reg'].'">'.$row['reg'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

The HTML in which the functions run:

```
<form method="post" name="regnskab" action="regnskab_beregn.php">
   <select name="bil"><? biler(); ?></select>
</form>
```

My problem is that the is no car pre selected, because they all have the select statement :/

Returns:

```
<select name="bil">
  <option selected="selected" value="OHO1241">OHO1241</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="QTX2314">QTX2314</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="QW20301">QW20301</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: Is there something you need assistance with? The code looks ok, except for the fact that `$result` is not in scope of the function using it.

Comment: Try <?php biler(); ?> instead (if it is your problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the *$selected* variable after using it otherwise it will always contain that value:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $selected = "";
   if ($row['reg'] == $_GET['bil']){
       $selected = 'selected="selected"';
   }                    
   echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['reg'].'">'.$row['reg'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: No problem :-) Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Once your `$selected` is set, it still exists. [My example](http://codepad.org/U9pHuoFG)

```
    function biler () {                         
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           if ($row['reg'] == $_GET['bil']){
               $selected = 'selected="selected"';
           }          
           else
           {
               $selected = "";
           }          
           echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['reg'].'">'.$row['reg'].'</option>';
        }
    }
```